# SugarCRM Account Contact relationship REST API

Tags: php, web-services, rest, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM 6.0.0 I need to create a relationship between an Account and a Contact via the REST webservices API.

I have tried these methods in both ways (Account -> Contact, Contact -> Account) to no avail:

```
$method = 'set_relationship';
$params = array(
  'module_name' => 'Accounts',
  'module_id' => $accountId,
  'link_field_name' => 'accounts_contacts',
  'related_ids' => array($userId)
);

$method = 'set_entry';
$params = array(
  'module_name' => 'Contacts',
  'name_value_list' => array(
      array('name' => 'id', 'value' => $userId),
      array('name' => 'accounts_contacts', 'value' => $accountId),
    ),
);
```

Numerous searches only give me these methods, or SOAP solutions. Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line about

```
'link_field_name' => 'accounts_contacts',
```

should be

```
'link_field_name' => 'contacts',
```

since the link field name is 'contacts' ( the relationship name is 'accounts_contacts' ).

Comment: That was indeed the solution. Thanks!